# AngularJS - Run function of child controller from parent controller

Tags: angularjs, components

I have read many questions on this but still can't find solution that will be clean and reusable enough.

What I tried and don't want to use:

- Events - $emit and $broadcast,
- DOM manipulation - for example angular.element('nameOfElement').scope() to access scope of child,
- $onChange in child component

**Simple example**

I've build simplified scenario of to present the problem.

On page there is `TimerComponent` that shows minutes and seconds. It have controller `TimerController` to change its state: `start()` and `stop()`. In example there are two of them, both presenting different values.

Timer template does not contain buttons to manipulate it - **that is intentional**. I want to start and stop the timer from other controller.

**Child-To-Parent communication**. I can pass `value` and function callback `onTick()` that will be run every second.

**Parent-To-Child communication**:
How could I run start() or stop() functions from parent component?

timer.component.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    TimerController.$inject = ['$interval']
    function TimerController($interval) {
        var ctrl = this;

        var interval = undefined;

        ctrl.start = start;
        ctrl.stop = stop;
        ctrl.minutes = minutes;
        ctrl.seconds = seconds;           

        function minutes() {
            return Math.floor(ctrl.value / 60);
        }

        function seconds() {
            return (ctrl.value % 60);
        }

        function start() {
            interval = $interval(function() {
                ctrl.value--;
                ctrl.onTick({ 'value': ctrl.value });
            }, 1000);
        }

        function stop() {
            $interval.cancel(interval);
        }
    }

    angular.module('app').component('timer', {
        bindings: {
            value: '<',
            onTick: '&'
        },

        templateUrl: 'timer.html',
        controller: TimerController
    });
})();
```

timer.html

```
<span ng-bind="$ctrl.minutes() + ':' + $ctrl.seconds()"></span>
```

app.html

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController as vm">
    <p>First timer: </p>
    <timer value="360" on-tick="vm.firstTimerTick(value)"></timer>

    <p>Second timer: </p>
    <timer value="120" on-tick="vm.secondTimerTick(value)"></timer>

    <p>
        <span ng-click="vm.startFirstTimer()">Start first timer</span>
    </p>
</body>
```

main.controller.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app').controller('MainController', MainController);

    function MainController() {
        var ctrl = this;
        ctrl.firstTimerTick = firstTimerTick;
        ctrl.secondTimerTick = secondTimerTick;
        ctrl.startFirstTimer = startFirstTimer;

        function firstTimerTick(value) {
            console.log('FirstTimer: ' + value);
        }

        function secondTimerTick(value) {
            console.log('SecondTimer: ' + value);
        }

        function startFirstTimer() {
            /* How to run start() function of TimerController here? */
        }

        function stopFirstTimer() {
            /* How to run start() function of TimerController here? */
        }
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to use the new [ngRef directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRef):

```
<timer ng-ref="vm.timerOne" value="360" on-tick="vm.firstTimerTick(value)">
</timer>
```

Then use it in the controller:

```
function startFirstTimer() {
    /* How to run start() function of TimerController here? */
    ctrl.timerOne.start();
}
```

The [ngRef directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRef) was introduced as a new feature with [AngularJS V1.7.1](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#new-features-1).

For more information, see [AngularJS ng-ref Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRef).